# Generated Rig not posing

Tags: modeling, armature

I generated a rig and parented it with automatic weights but the model suddenly separated 90 degrees to the rig outline. [image]
Here is a video link of how I attempted to generate the rig and got that problem: (https://streamable.com/eawzbr)

Comment: Note: In the video you can see that I removed the sword and shield (scutum) out of the Roman Soldier collection as they are not to be part of the generated rig. Hope that was the right thing to do. So basically I need the soldier to naturally be within the rig outline and then begin to access the posing feature.

Comment: Have you applied the Rotation and Scale of the mesh (Ctrl + A) before you parented it? Also, pull the elbows a little bit backward and push the knees a bit forward. Don't make them completely straight (meta rig). The IK of the generated rig needs to know in which direction it should bend the bones.

Comment: Probably the mesh has a parent before the rigging. You have to apply the transforms for both at the same time.

Comment: @Blunder you can actually use any bone’s IK settings to keep it from bending in the wrong direction from IK. I discovered this just recently.

Comment: @Blunder .... Adjusted the knees and elbows now .. thanks. I didn't actually use the Rotation and Scale of the mesh (Ctrl A) before, but instead used the All Transforms selection in the list from Ctrl A. But this time, I did try the rotation and scale but still didn't work out. I have attached another video of what I did this time (not much difference from the first one): https://streamable.com/0thjl3